# Связный список, оператор -> (С++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, список, односвязный-список

Есть код:

```
struct Element      //структура задающая элемент односвязного списка
{
    int data;       //информационное поле для хранения данных
    Element *next;  //указатель на следующий элемент
} *start, *current;

void create_list(int a)
{
    current = new Element;
    current->data = a;
    current->next = NULL;
    start = current;
}

void new_element(int a)
{
    Element *q;
    q = new Element;
    q->data = a;
    q->next = current->next;
    current->next = q;
}

void delete_element(int a)
{
    while (current->data != a)
    {
        current = current->next;
        if (current->data == a)
        {
            delete current;
        }
    }
}
```

Не совсем понял, что происходит в этих строчках:

```
current->next = NULL;
```

функции `create_list(int)`

и

```
q->data = a;
q->next = current->next;
current->next = q;
```

функции `new_element(int)`

Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Первый -

```
current->next = NULL;
```

просто устанавливает элемент, на который указывает `current`, последним в списке - за ним (`next`) ничего нет.

```
q->data = a;
q->next = current->next;
current->next = q;
```

Это просто вставляет элемент после `current` - теперь новый элемент `q` указывает туда же, куда раньше указывал элемент, на который указывал `current`, а он теперь указывает на `q`.

Вот примерный набросок - простите уж за отсутствие художественного таланта :) Видите? разорвали связь и воткнули туда новый элемент...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Красивая ручка! =)

Comment: @entithat Так лучше? :)

Comment: @entithat Можно, но не за деньги :) Рекомендую обратить внимание на это: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6654/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-2018?cb=1

Comment: Впечатляет! Ради такого подарка стоит попробовать :)

Comment: Посмотрите в коде на функцию удаления элемента,пожалуйста, скажите,что там не так?

Comment: Вы должны соответствующим образом изменить поля - элемент, *предшествующий* удаляемому, должен сначала получить то же значение поля `next`, что было у удаляемого - чтоб цепочку не порвать. И только после этого можно удалять сам элемент.